Сортировка файлов в Linux без использования конвейера
Нужно написать команду,которая выводит отсортированные строки файлов 1.txt и 2.txt без повторов,не пользуясь конвейером (пайпом) |.
Команда должна быть не длиннее 17 символов.
Содержимое файла 1.txt:
0
1
2
3
4
5

Содержимое файла 2.txt
5
4
3
333
2
999
1
777

ожидаемый результат:
0
1
2
3
333
4
5
777
999

Я пытался решить данную задачу при помощи команды sort -u 1.txt 2.txt

И что не получилось?

И откуда вообще такие странные ограничения?

Я не могу понять ,как можно модифицировть эту команду при помощи масок или регулярных выражений.

UPD: задача учебная,поэтому такие странные ограничения.

sort -u {1,2}.txt. А вообще требования идиотские, не стоит учиться там, где такие задания.

А, ну ещё можно так sort -u *, если считать что никаких других файлов в папке нет.

@user207200 , да, в этой команде надо просто добавить перечисление от 1 до 2.
P.S. смысл данной задачи показать гибкость команд *nix подобных ОС.

@AlexeyTen думаю, тогда не было бы имен файлов в условии.

@AlexeyTen , подразумевается,что в каталоге есть другие файлы.Поэтому решение sort -u * неверное.

sort -u 1.txt 2.txt Выводит "ожидаемый результат" , что именно не устраивает? sort -u 1.* 3.* тоже выводит "ожидаемый результат"

возможно у данной задачи неполное условие, так как если нужно учитывать точные имена файлов в решении то это минус 10 символов при минимальном их указании --  {1,2}.txt где также учитывая начальный пробел, то есть на саму команду с ключами в таком случае остаётся только 7 символов с которыми при всём желании не разгуляешься
